# How will MVVM affect my access to my domain context?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I'm looking at taking the application I've written in Silverlight / C# / RIA Services and making it more robust by doing it in MVVM for testability.  My question is this: in order to make it easy for forms to add / remove / update items, I created a static resource in a file called DomainService.xaml that all ria services queries were based off of.

```
<ds:MyDomainContext x:Key="MyDomainContext" />
```

This allowed me to have all the queries using the same context so that I wouldn't get errors about an entity being attached to one context and getting affected by another context working on the same entity.  My DomainDataSources ended up looking something like this:

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Name="discountsDataSource" LoadSize="10" DomainContext="{StaticResource MyDomainContext}" QueryName="GetDiscounts" />
```

This practice seems to have worked rather well.  But I'm not seeing anything like it in the MVVM world.  How does the data layer for an MVVM application keep all the context's straight?  Will I still be able to use datapagers as easily as before, or will there have to be large amounts of plumbing code put in to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of an Depndency Injection/IoC container to manage your objects.  I personally have found Unity to be great for this purpose.  You simply need to tell your container to use a lifetime manager that keeps a single object and then in every class you request that object from your UnityContainer.

Ex for Unity:

```
// Upon creation of the container
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<MyDomainContext>(new ContainerLifetimeManager());

// In your individual model classes
container.Resolve<MyDomainContext>();
```

As long as you pass the container around between classes (which is trivially easy if you use the container to construct all of your model objects) then resolve will always return the same context you requested.